# updating PrimeFaces Calendar component with dates from back-end

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use calendar component from PrimeFaces.

```
    <p:calendar id="hotelCalendar"
                mode="inline"
                beforeShowDay="disableDates" 
                pages="1">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{apartments.handleDateSelect}" 
              oncomplete="loadDisabledDates();" update="hotelCalendar"/>
    </p:calendar>
```

**Logic**: when a user clicks on the date, back-end should process this date and set it as disabled.
After that calendar receives updated array of disabled dates from back-end(using ajax request), reload all the dates(using beforeShowDay) and mark them with different colors. Available - green, disabled - red.

The problem: Calendar `update` is executed almost instantly after `dateSelect` event. That's why I don't see current changes until the next click.

Question:

1. How could I force update to be executed after js `loadDisabledDates()` is completed?
2. Is there any other way to achieve such functionality? Probably with binding Calendar component to bean?

Comment: which version of Primefaces are you using. Accordiong to my knowledge Primefaces 3.5 has no option of handling Multiple dates.

Comment: Calendar invokes beforeShowDate() before showing each date. What do you mean by "handling Multiple dates"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `oncomplete` runs indeed after `update`. I'm not sure why you expected the other way round, [the documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/ajax.html) says clearly so.

Basically, this is the event invocation order:

- `onclick` handler is invoked
- ajax request is prepared with form data based on `process`
- `onbegin` handler is invoked
- ajax request is sent
- ajax response is successfully retrieved (HTTP status code is 200)
- `onsuccess` handler is invoked
- ajax updates are performed in HTML DOM based on `update`
- `oncomplete` handler is invoked

So, provided that you want to execute some script after executing the ajax response but before updating the HTML DOM, just use `onsuccess` instead of `oncomplete`.

Comment: "documentation says clearly so" where exactly? I cannot find the execution order.

Comment: I quote from `oncomplete` description: *"Client side callback execute when ajax request is completed and dom is updated."*

Comment: ok, thanks. Now with `onstart` the order is following: 1. onstart(`loadDisabledDates`) 2. ajax request(`apartments.handleDateSelect`) 3. `update`. But I need 1. ajax request(`apartments.handleDateSelect`). 2. listener(`loadDisabledDates`) 3. `update`

Comment: That wasn't clear from the question at all. In that case, use `onsuccess` instead. I updated the answer with the ordering, for the case it wasn't clear to you.